# AWS EC2 machine giving "pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract not installed or it's not in your path"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to use tesseract-ocr on AWS EC2 machine using python.

I have install `tesseract-ocr`, `pytesseract` and set `TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/tessdata...` but still geting below error while calling `image_to_string` method of pytesseract.

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract not
>   installed or it's not in your path

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `tesseract` installation folder to path too. if you have done that already, you might need to restart once or at least sign out and sign in. TESSDATA is the path you give for tesseract to access the language data.

Comment: I have updated  PATH variable to location, where langauge model has been kept but it was still showing same error. EC2 machine restart i need to try. i will keep you updated

Comment: Not to the path of language model, path to tesseract.exe

Comment: This is on Linux machine..so i think .exe is on Windows...it may be binary files created. Please suggest.

Comment: did you install it using apt-get?

Comment: it is RHEL machine on aws ..so only yum and pip are working..apt-get not working

Comment: i need to pass tesseract executable location but not able to figure where is it ?

Comment: did you build  it from source?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have installed "pytesseract" with PIP

On Ubuntu ::

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

On MAC ::

```
brew install tesseract
```

After installing with the above commands, the problem will be resolved